# How to export Azure Prices REST API to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest, web-scraping

I would like to save the whole Azure Prices REST API to CSV.

In order to do so I have to query the endpoint https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices which ends with a:

`"NextPageLink":"https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?$skip=100","Count":100}`

[image]

I wrote a Python scripts that could help me grab that `NextPageLink` and loop it into a function:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd 
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta

start = timer()
NextPageLink = "https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices"

def GetJSON(NextPageLink):
    wjdata = requests.get(NextPageLink).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(wjdata)
    df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
    if 'NextPageLink' in wjdata:
        print (timer(), wjdata['NextPageLink'])
        NextPageLink = wjdata['NextPageLink']
        return NextPageLink

GetJSON(NextPageLink)
```

The script is quite simple but it just saves the first page and doesn't query the `NextPageLink`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all data from the API you can try (there are 4558 requests total):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices"

all_data = []
while True:
    print(url)
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    all_data.extend(data["Items"])
    if data["NextPageLink"]:
        url = data["NextPageLink"]
    else:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
......

https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?$skip=455600
https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?$skip=455700
https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?$skip=455800
```

| currencyCode | tierMinimumUnits | retailPrice | unitPrice | armRegionName | location | effectiveStartDate | meterId | meterName | productId | skuId | availabilityId | productName | skuName | serviceName | serviceId | serviceFamily | unitOfMeasure | type | isPrimaryMeterRegion | armSkuName | reservationTerm | effectiveEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 0 | 3 | 3 | southindia | IN South | 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z | ff92c14c-af83-412e-9144-a2542dfe0b4f | Certificate Renewal Request | DZH318Z0BQG0 | DZH318Z0BQG0/0001 |  | Key Vault | Premium | Key Vault | DZH3157JCZ2M | Security | 1 | Consumption | False |  | nan | nan |
| USD | 0 | 3 | 3 | southcentralus | US South Central | 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z | ff92c14c-af83-412e-9144-a2542dfe0b4f | Certificate Renewal Request | DZH318Z0BQG0 | DZH318Z0BQG0/002Q |  | Key Vault | Standard | Key Vault | DZH3157JCZ2M | Security | 1 | Consumption | False |  | nan | nan |
| USD | 0 | 3 | 3 | jioindiawest | IN West Jio | 2021-04-15T00:00:00Z | ff92c14c-af83-412e-9144-a2542dfe0b4f | Certificate Renewal Request | DZH318Z0BQG0 | DZH318Z0BQG0/004V |  | Key Vault | Premium | Key Vault | DZH3157JCZ2M | Security | 1 | Consumption | False |  | nan | nan |
| USD | 0 | 3 | 3 | germanywestcentral | DE West Central | 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z | ff92c14c-af83-412e-9144-a2542dfe0b4f | Certificate Renewal Request | DZH318Z0BQG0 | DZH318Z0BQG0/003Q |  | Key Vault | Premium | Key Vault | DZH3157JCZ2M | Security | 1 | Consumption | False |  | nan | nan |
| USD | 0 | 3 | 3 | westeurope | EU West | 2016-12-01T00:00:00Z | ff92c14c-af83-412e-9144-a2542dfe0b4f | Certificate Renewal Request | DZH318Z0BQG0 | DZH318Z0BQG0/001Z |  | Key Vault | Premium | Key Vault | DZH3157JCZ2M | Security | 1 | Consumption | False |  | nan | nan |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Strange, after 1h it finished with  ´ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'´ and ´ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tabulate'.  Use pip or conda to install tabulate.´ . I will now install it and hoefully after 1h it will not fail

Comment: The .to_markdown() function from Pandas requires tabulate.