# How to pivot 3 rows to 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting, pivot

After a lot of effort and [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438621/how-to-export-azure-prices-rest-api-to-csv)  I have arrived to download the Azure Retail Price list.

For every resource I have the unitPrice and the price for 1 Year and 3 Years:

| currencyCode | retailPrice | unitPrice | location | meterId | meterName | skuId | productName | serviceId | unitOfMeasure | type | isPrimaryMeterRegion | reservationTerm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | 2739.0533 | 2739.0533 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/003T | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Reservation | True | 3 Years |
| CHF | 0.2376 | 0.2376 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/00S9 | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Consumption | True | NULL |
| CHF | 1325.4761 | 1325.4761 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/003S | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Reservation | True | 1 Year |

I would like to pivot the unitPrice where the reservationTerm is 1Year and 3 Years and obtain something like this:

| currencyCode | retailPrice | unitPrice | location | meterId | meterName | skuId | productName | serviceId | unitOfMeasure | type | isPrimaryMeterRegion | reservationTerm | unitPrice_Hour | 3Years_Reservation | 3Year_Reservation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | 2739.0533 | 2739.0533 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/003T | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Reservation | True | 3 Years |  |  |  |
| CHF | 0.2376 | 0.2376 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/00S9 | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Consumption | True | NULL | 0.2376 | 1325.4761 | 2739.0533 |
| CHF | 1325.4761 | 1325.4761 | EU West | 7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117 | D4 v3/D4s v3 | DZH318Z0BQ4K/003S | Virtual Machines Dv3 Series | DZH313Z7MMC8 | 1 Hour | Reservation | True | 1 Year |  |  |  |

I followed a few guides and I ended up creating this test script:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [currencyCode]
    ,[retailPrice]
    ,[unitPrice]
    ,[location]
    ,[meterId]
    ,[meterName]
    ,[skuId]
    ,[productName]
    ,[serviceId]
    ,[unitOfMeasure]
    ,[type]
    ,[isPrimaryMeterRegion]
    ,[reservationTerm]
FROM [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE meterId = '7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117'
    AND isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
pivot(MAX(unitPrice) FOR reservationTerm IN (
            NULL
            ,'1 Year'
            ,'3 Years'
            )) AS piv;
```

But it returns the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.

What am I doing wrong?

You can create the table this way:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Testing]    Script Date: 11/22/2022 12:49:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Testing](
    [currencyCode] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [retailPrice] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [unitPrice] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [location] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [meterId] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [meterName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [skuId] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [productName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [serviceId] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [unitOfMeasure] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [isPrimaryMeterRegion] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [reservationTerm] [nvarchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Testing] ([currencyCode], [retailPrice], [unitPrice], [location], [meterId], [meterName], [skuId], [productName], [serviceId], [unitOfMeasure], [type], [isPrimaryMeterRegion], [reservationTerm]) VALUES (N'CHF', N'2739.0533', N'2739.0533', N'EU West', N'7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117', N'D4 v3/D4s v3', N'DZH318Z0BQ4K/003T', N'Virtual Machines Dv3 Series', N'DZH313Z7MMC8', N'1 Hour', N'Reservation', N'True', N'3 Years')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Testing] ([currencyCode], [retailPrice], [unitPrice], [location], [meterId], [meterName], [skuId], [productName], [serviceId], [unitOfMeasure], [type], [isPrimaryMeterRegion], [reservationTerm]) VALUES (N'CHF', N'0.2376', N'0.2376', N'EU West', N'7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117', N'D4 v3/D4s v3', N'DZH318Z0BQ4K/00S9', N'Virtual Machines Dv3 Series', N'DZH313Z7MMC8', N'1 Hour', N'Consumption', N'True', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Testing] ([currencyCode], [retailPrice], [unitPrice], [location], [meterId], [meterName], [skuId], [productName], [serviceId], [unitOfMeasure], [type], [isPrimaryMeterRegion], [reservationTerm]) VALUES (N'CHF', N'1325.4761', N'1325.4761', N'EU West', N'7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117', N'D4 v3/D4s v3', N'DZH318Z0BQ4K/003S', N'Virtual Machines Dv3 Series', N'DZH313Z7MMC8', N'1 Hour', N'Reservation', N'True', N'1 Year')
GO
```

**EDIT:** After your comment I tried to wrap it up and I did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
    ) AS t
pivot(MAX(unitPrice) FOR reservationTerm IN (
            NULL
            ,'1 Year'
            ,'3 Years'
            )) AS p;
```

but it says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.`.
I don't see where the error is...

EDIT 2:

I tried with conditional aggregation but it's not working:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [unitPrice]
    ,[meterId]
    ,[reservationTerm]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN reservationTerm = '3 Years'
            THEN unitPrice
        WHEN reservationTerm = '1 Years'
            THEN unitPrice
        ELSE 'hello'
        END
FROM [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
GROUP BY meterId
    ,[unitPrice]
    ,reservationTerm
```

[image]

The idea is to generate 1 column for the 3 years and 1 column for the 1 year.

**EDIT 3:** Following @Larnu [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/aaGY-Evj) I put in place 2 different approach here: PIVOT and Aggregation:

```
/* Example with PIVOT */
SELECT 
    P.[meterId]
    ,P.[3 Years]
    ,P.[1 Year]
FROM (select * from [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE meterId = '7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117'
    AND isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
)V 
PIVOT (sum(unitPrice) FOR reservationTerm IN ([3 Years],[1 Year])) P

/* Example with Aggregation */
SELECT 
    [meterId]
    ,(CASE WHEN reservationTerm = '3 Years' THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [3 Years]
    ,(CASE WHEN reservationTerm = '1 Year'  THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [1 Years]
    ,(CASE WHEN reservationTerm = NULL  THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [Is_Null]
FROM (select * from [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE meterId = '7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117'
    AND isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
)V
```

But none of the two is working; they are returning the prices on different rows:

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I suggest using conditional aggregation; it is far better than the clunky `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: The problem, however, is that `PIVOT` is an operator on a (derived) table; it doesn't go after the `WHERE`. So you need to do `SELECT {Pivot Columns} FROM ({Your Derived Table Definition}) {Dervived Table Alias} PIVOT ({Pivot Declaration});`

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I will check the conditional aggregation.

Comment: Nah, there is no easy way to use conditional aggregation in this scenario, `PIVOT` looks better here

Comment: Considering that `PIVOT` and conditional aggregation do *the same thing* your statement makes no sense.

Comment: I cannot use `,sum(case when reservationTerm = '3 Years' then unitPrice else 0 end ) as '3 Years'` because that `unitPrice` need to come only from that unique `meterId`.

Comment: So `meterID` should be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you are right @Larnu. Should I just delete this question or should I post the solution made by you?

Comment: If you have solved the problem yourself, you can always post the solution; self answered questions aren't frowned upon, provided that both are good quality.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, I posted another Edit. I hope you understand why Conditional aggregation is not working here. I need to create 2 columns

Comment: You can have more than one conditional aggregate... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aaGY-Evj)

Comment: *"I tried with conditional aggregation but it's not working:"* There's no [aggregation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in that query; part of having conditional aggregation is that you *aggregate*.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I added EDIT 3 to show you the 2 examples that I created following your link

Comment: *"`/* Example with Aggregation */`"* where is the "aggregation"? There's no `SUM`, no `MAX`, no `AVG`, etc, etc; there is no aggregation in your "example with aggregation".

Comment: you are right, now I have everything on one row. But why PIVOT is not working?

Comment: I just noticed, you are trying to `SUM` your column `unitPrice` which is defined as an `nvarchar(250)`; you can't `SUM` an `nvarchar` as it doesn't make sense to. What is the `SUM` of the values `N'abc'` and `N'def'`? What about `N'bacon', N'cheese'`?

Comment: Ha,ha, `N'bacon'` + `N'cheese'` = `Crispy Bacon Burger`. I will fix than now. Thank you @Larnu

Comment: BTW, I changed `unitPrice` from `nvarchar(250)` to `money` and `SUM` to `MAX` but the problem persists. I still see 3 rows

Comment: Recommended reading; [Avoid use of the MONEY and SMALLMONEY datatypes (BP022)](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a millions to @Larnu that linked me this [do-it-your-own](https://dbfiddle.uk/aaGY-Evj) link:

```
/* Example with PIVOT */
SELECT 
    P.[meterId]
    ,P.[3 Years]
    ,P.[1 Year]
FROM (select * from [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE meterId = '7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117'
    AND isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
)V 
PIVOT (sum(unitPrice) FOR reservationTerm IN ([3 Years],[1 Year])) P


/* Example with Aggregation */
SELECT 
    [meterId]
    ,max(CASE WHEN reservationTerm = '3 Years' THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [3 Years]
    ,max(CASE WHEN reservationTerm = '1 Year'   THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [1 Years]
    ,max(CASE WHEN reservationTerm IS NULL  THEN unitPrice ELSE '' END) as [Is_Null]
FROM (select * from [dbo].[Azure_Retail_Prices]
WHERE meterId = '7766bed4-f4db-4593-9cc5-ebff48957117'
    AND isPrimaryMeterRegion != 'False'
)V 
group by [meterId]
```

[image]

I still have some problems with `PIVOT` but the aggregation works.